# Way to make a larger ipad app perform quickly and fetch data from server

Tags: ios

I am making an app which has to fetch the list of the catalogs from server may be list can be 100 items or can go to 1000 items so i am confused about performance i made proto  getting server data each time app opened from server thorough JSON it takes time and user can not wait so any idea or way to follow so that we can make the performance of the app faster.

Comment: I would guess every 10th question is describing a problem in the same category like yours. Depending on your particular problem, I can assure your there are at least one up to a few solutions. You may now search harder on SO (which will definitely reveal a dozens of answers), or you may describe your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to only fetch a limited number of items at a time.  For example, if these are items displayed in a table view, fetch 20-50 at a time, and wait till the user starts scrolling to fetch more.